# Why OAuth2 is not allowing to contain fragment identifier in redirect URI?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

According to the OAuth2.0 [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1.2), the redirect URI should not contain a fragment identifier.

> The redirection endpoint URI MUST be an absolute URI as defined by
> [RFC3986] Section 4.3. The endpoint URI MAY include an
> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" formatted (per Appendix B) query
> component ([RFC3986] Section 3.4), which MUST be retained when adding
> additional query parameters. The endpoint URI MUST NOT include a
> fragment component.

Are there any specific reasons for why the spec has made such limitations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

URL fragment never leaves your browser. They are intended to be used by front end (That mean if you put a hash fragment to a URL in your browser and visit it, fragment won't reach the server end).

So when authorization server redirects via user agent, fragment will only stay on the user agent. From OAuth perspective this could bring unwanted complexity and security vulnerability. This is further highlighted under [Insufficient Redirect URI Validation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-13#section-4.1) in best practice draft.

Comment: so when the oauth server redirects to the browser, the browser when sending a get request to the redirect url would not send the hash. this will not be a problem if your front end app handles the url, as it would be able to read the hash, but would be a problem if your BE handles the redirect url.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason against the fragment part is its use in the [Implicit flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.2). Since the syntax of the URL fragment part is not standardized, the OAuth2 server would not know how to add its information (access_token and such) to the existing fragment value of the redirect URL.

Comment: Now the OAuth community recommends the authorization code flow for Single page apps which run on the broswer. Is the second reasoning that the fragment cannot be read by the app still valid?

Comment: That's true @farasath, thank you for the correction. I removed that part.